# broadcasted lstsq (least squares)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of 3x2 matrices, let's say 777 of them, and just as many right-hand sides of size 3. For each of them, I would like to know the least squared solution, so I'm doing

```
import numpy

A = numpy.random.rand(3, 2, 777)
b = numpy.random.rand(3, 777)

for k in range(777):
    numpy.linalg.lstsq(A[..., k], b[..., k])
```

That works, but is slow. I'd much rather compute all the solutions in one go, but upon

```
numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, b)
```

I'm getting

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 3-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

Any hints on how to broadcast `numpy.linalg.lstsq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can make use of the fact that if `A = U \Sigma V^T` is the singular value decomposition of `A`,

```
x = V \Sigma^+ U^T b
```

is the least-squares solution to `Ax = b`. [SVD is broadcasted in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html). It now only requires a bit of fiddling with `einsum`s to get it all right:

```
A = numpy.random.rand(7, 3, 2)
b = numpy.random.rand(7, 3)
for k in range(7):
    x, res, rank, sigma = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A[k], b[k])
    print(x)

print

u, s, v = numpy.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
uTb = numpy.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', u, b)
xx = numpy.einsum('ijk, ij->ik', v, uTb / s)
print(xx)
```

Comment: I'm curious how the speed compares here. Is it faster?